# Mysql column sorting of string data

Tags: mysql, sorting

**NOTE :** I have edited my question because of my input data present in database table.

I have a table and it consists varchar data. The data present inside that column is like this.

```
"bcd"
cde
abcd
'xxx'
(zzz)
```

Now I want to sort according to alphabetical order. I have tried this query

```
select my_col from tbl_user order by ltrim(REPLACE(my_col,'"', '')) ASC
```

Its' output is as follows :

```
'xxx'
(zzz)
abcd
"bcd"
cde
```

But my desired output is, means while sorting it has to sort according to alphabetical order whether `"` present or not.

```
abcd
"bcd"
cde
'xxx'
(zzz)
```

How can I achieve this??. any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a replace on the quotes, for example:

```
select my_col 
from tbl_user 
order by ltrim(REPLACE(my_col,'"', '')) ASC
```

But this would add a lot of overhead... maybe there is a built-in solution which would be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from 
tlb_user
order by replace(my_col, '"', ');
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dddc1/5)

Answer (score 1):

Trim() away the quotes when sorting;

```
...
order by
   trim(both '"' from `your_column`) asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select my_col 
from tbl_user 
order by
  SUBSTR(my_col, 2) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can ignore the special characters by using `mysql_real_escape_string`
This link may help you : http://in.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string